# Unable to populate data from form fields into the action class data members in struts2

Tags: struts2

I created a jsp page which has a form , I am trying to populate the data members of the action classfrom this form, after submitting the form the control is being moved to the action class but the action class data members are not populated.

my jsp page looks like this.

```
 <s:actionerror /> 
 <s:form  action = "retrieve"  method="post">
        <s:textfield  name = "form1" value = "form1" />
         <s:textfield  name="cid"/>
         <s:submit type = "submit" name = "sub" value="submit"/>          
 </s:form>
```

my action class looks like this.

```
     public class CustomerUpdate extends ActionSupport {

     private String form1 ;

     private String cid ;


         public String execute() {

                  System.out.println(form1) ;
                  System.out.println(cid) ;

    }
```

Here  after submission of form I expect form1 variable in action class should have the value as "form1" but it is still null.

can anyone help where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: sorry actually it is system.out.println(form1); and system.out.println(cid) ; no quotes........

Comment: Why do you expect form1 variable in action class?

Comment: Do you have public getters/setters for your action properties? What's the *actual* code, since this code won't even compile?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have configuration file that maps action class to your jsp file.
normally configuration file is an xml file in your src folder. example:

```
<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="retrieve" class="CustomerUpdate">
            <result>/xxx.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>  
</struts>
```

Since your execute method is of return type string, return some string. Based on string returned from execute method you can redirect. otherwise change it to void.

If you already have properly configured action class with your jsp, then for using member variables, code in jsp might look like:

```
<form  action = "retrieve"  method="post">
        <s:textfield  name = "form1" value = "${form1}" />
         <s:textfield  name="${cid}"/>
         <s:submit type = "submit" name = "sub" value="submit"/>          
 </form>
```

and also since member variable are private:

```
system.out.println(getForm1);
system.out.println(getCid);
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

At first place, your code will not compile.

As i assume that ***struts.xml*** file contains below lines,

```
<action name="retrieve" class="CustomerUpdate" method="execute">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Update the ***CustomerUpdate*** as below and check the program.

```
public class CustomerUpdate extends ActionSupport {

     private String form1 ;

     private String cid ;


         public String execute() {

                  System.out.println(form1) ;
                  System.out.println(cid) ;


        return "success";

    }

    //getter & setter for form1 & cid 
}
```

please try out the above code sample and i think it will work.

Comment: I've removed modeldriven from your answer to avoid confusions. OP doesn't use it and it isn't needed.